# Dynamic tab view with multiple API calls using Flutter

Tags: flutter, dynamic, tabview

I want to create a Flutter tab view, tab count and content must be based on the multiple API calls.
There is 3 section in each tab and each section get data from a separate API.
What is the best method to create a solution? Bloc is the best way to manage the state.

I tried to implement a CustomTabView and set tab data but I'm facing various issues and wired tab combinations. Please help me to solve this problem.
Thank you

Comment: Can you show what you've tried until now and where you are facing your problem?

Answer (score 0):

This is a general question and doesn't have debug details, so the answer can seem a bit dumb.
Anyway,

The best case is to have a separate block for each section.
But you can also have all requests in one block. It is not recommended at all, but I will explain the method.

**For call Multi api in one bloC:**

when you use the state manager bloC , you have a method named mapEventToState that calls a second method of Stream type according to your request.
It is in this method that you return the State. In order to call several APIs, you need to define a dynamic variable here for each one. Then connect to each API here and fill these variables with the corresponding response.

To return the result, it is better if all variables containing the response containing statusCode were successful, then the state of this bloC should be succeeded.

```
    ...  
    @override
      Stream<MyBlocState> mapEventToState(MyBlocEvent event) async* {
        if (event is CallTheAPIsEvent) {
          yield ApisHaveNeedCalles();
        }


// second method of Stream
        Stream<MyBlocState> ApisHaveNeedCalles() {
          var resultApi1;
          var resultApi2;
          var resultApi3;
          try {
            resultApi1 = _repository.getAPI1();
            resultApi2 = _repository.getAPI2();
            resultApi3 = _repository.getAPI3();
          } catch (e) {
            yield ErrorState();
          }
    
    
          if (resultApi1 != null && resultApi2 != null && resultApi13 != null) {
            yield SuccessState(resultList: [resultApi1, resultApi2, resultApi3 ]);
          }
    
          // more event handling
        }
    ...
```